# SSAS cube drill down, relational data

Tags: excel, ssas, cube

FactTable (cube)

- Id
- CustomerId
- SomeId
- AnotherId
- Price

Customer Dimension

- Id,
- CustomerName

Now, I connect to Analysis Services from Excel and get the pivot table added. When I double click a price in the pivot table I drill down and get all the rows that makes out the price/cell I double clicked.

The problem now is that I would like to be presented to the CustomerName instead (or also) of the CustomerId - as one of the columns. I have juggled around with cube, dimenensions and source tables, but I just can't get it right. It just returns the Id columns.

It's probably right in front of me, but I don't see it.
The cube is built in Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each dimension member can have different sources for key and name. You set key to CustomerID and Name to CustomerName.